# RxJS BehaviorSubject getValue inconsistency after value emitted (while testing in Jest)

Tags: typescript, rxjs, jestjs, rxjs-marbles

I don't understand why `.getValue()` returns the default value of the Observable and not the last value emitted. When testing the Observable, it correctly returns the emitted value.

```js
class TestA {
  readonly aSource: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  getA(): number {
    return this.aSource.getValue();
  }

  promise(): void {
    Promise.reject()
      .catch(() => {
        this.aSource.next(2);

        console.log(this.getA()); // Outputs: 2
      });
  }
}

describe('TestA', () => {
  it('promise', () => {
    const a = new TestA();
    a.promise();

    // Test 1 OK
    expect(a.aSource.asObservable()).toBeObservable(hot('a', {a: 2}));

    // Test 2 FAIL (returns null)
    expect(a.aSource.getValue()).toEqual(2);

    // Test 3 FAIL (returns null)
    expect(a.getA()).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```

To clarify, the `getValue()` method works fine outsude tests, it only fails while testing with Jest.

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, my assumption was that `Promise.reject()` would be treated as sync code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if I do `Promise.reject()` the code doesn't turnout to be synchronous, so in this case you need to flush execution queue in order to test that code.

A solution using Angular helper functions would be:

```js
  it('promise', fakeAsync(() => {
    const a = new TestA();
    a.promise();

    flush();

    expect(a.aSource.asObservable()).toBeObservable(hot('a', {a: 2}));
    expect(a.aSource.getValue()).toEqual(2);
    expect(a.getA()).toEqual(2);
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is asynchronous nature of callback function of `catch`. So  I think if you  wrap  your expect statement in  `setTimeout` , and  run test as  async it became green.

Answer (score 0):

The first assertion is asynchronous. Internally, it'll resolve the `Observable`, so you'll indeed get `2`.

However, while this is pending, the other two assertions are triggered. And they are synchronous. Nothing guarantee you that, at that time, the `.next` call has been done. So you still get the initial value.

That's why I would recommend to not use the `.getValue` method of `BehaviorSubject` and rather subscribe to it properly. That way, you'll avoid such confusion by always doing asynchronous operations.

Comment: I would rather aside of subscribing to the Observable do more tests that contains the wrapper function, so since `Promise.reject()` is not sync I need to flush microtasks and then it passes all tests.